# Why is SWTOR not downloading through EA's Origin service?

Tags: origin, star-wars-the-old-republic

So, I'm about to download SWTOR as written here http://www.swtor.com/early-access.

But it seems like I have to download the client by itself, not via the Origin program by EA, even if the game shows up in Origin.

Will the download be for the Origin service (linking it to Origin at the end) or does it have nothing to do with the service?

In short, will I have to redownload it after the Early Access (Dec. 20th) even if I download it now?

Comment: Maybe they banned you from your games for using their forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While SWTOR [does require an Origin/EA account](http://www.swtor.com/info/faq#170974), it uses [its own launcher](http://www.swtor.com/preorder/faq#305172) (which is its downloader/patcher).

The Early Access client is the [same downloader and game client](http://www.swtor.com/preorder/faq#305157) that the final game will use.  This is kind of the point of Early Access, to have a copy of the final game before its official launch.  However, be aware that they will be [taking the servers down for maintenance on the 19th/20th](http://www.swtor.com/preorder/faq#305140), prior to the game's official launch.

Answer (score 1):

The Star Wars: TOR account is the same as your EA account. TOR uses its own client (which you can download from your account at [swtor.com](http://swtor.com/)) and doesn't depend on Origin. The client downloads the game used for the beta, early access,  and the final release/updates.  The download is over 25 GB.

(I know all this for fact because I did it all and started playing.)